# Use meanjs with remote public folder

Tags: node.js, cordova, meanjs

I have a project that is done with meanjs.
However, I wonder how I can separate the client from the server of this project.
I must publish the project (/public) in an app with cordova/phonegap. And let the server (/app) running somewhere on the internet.
I know the process of compiling the cordova app and configure the server.
But, How can I separate the layer client x server in meanjs?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you need help with.  Your node server code should be entirely independent from your client code already as it runs separately.

Comment: Well, I've managed to create a webApp based on meanjs. I'd now like to create an Mobile App using cordova/phonegap to also access this webApp database. My question is how could I use the front-end part already done as the basis for this Mobile App?